# Flutter web feels laggy after running for 2 hour continuously

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, optimization, websocket

I Had build a web app using flutter in which I used websocket to fetch gold and silver live price and used stream builder to show the data in ui,the problem is that after running my web app for continues 2 hours the web get lags and has a choppy effect and the data from websocket is not shown correct,I mean not the live price rather the price get stucks.Is there any way i Can fix this and Improve my flutter web app optimization.
[This is My Hosted Web App](https://demo.bullionview.com),
The Web app is hosted in aws amplify.